# Raspberry Pi can't save an object on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, raspberry-pi

I followed the guide on the parse website: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#embedded/raspberrypi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <parse.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
ParseClient client = parseInitialize("APP ID", "CLIENT ID");

parseSendRequest(client, "POST", "/1/classes/TestObject", "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}", NULL);
return 0;
}
```

The code above, as shown in the quickstart guide, could not create an object on my app. The test button shows that there are no registered devices.

I am trying to upload images taken from the pi camera to Parse.com. Is there any  alternative way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

ParseClient client = parseInitialize(**"APP ID", "CLIENT ID"**);
You have to put your actual APP_ID and CLIENT_ID there.

You can get them in your *parse.com app link>settings>keys*